# How to add the first four digits in to another list

Tags: python, list

I want to take the first four digits from the already shuffled list and add them to a new list. I thought of append but all it does is return the whole list 4 times.

```
base = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
random.shuffle(base)
correct = []
for i in range(4):
    correct.append(base)
print(correct)
```

Comment: You should have a look at slicing in python

Comment: `base` is the entire list. You want to append the `i`th element of `base`. How would you get the `i`th element of `base`?

Comment: Well yes, you append `base`, and `base` is the whole list. You meant `append(base[i])`. But why not `correct = base[:4]`.

Comment: In particular you can solve it using `base[:4]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it like this:

```
import random

base = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
random.shuffle(base)
correct = base[:4]
print(correct)
```

This works because of [list slicing](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-list-slicing/)

If for whatever reason you want to avoid using list slicing here is how you would do it in a way you originally tried.

```
base = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
random.shuffle(base)
correct = []
for i in range(4):
    correct.append(base[i])
print(correct)
```